# [ROS2-Crystal] rclcpp::executors Interrupt guard condition

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp, ros-crystal

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

After upgrading to ROS2 crystal clemmys, I am receiving a error message:

> Failed to create interrupt guard
> condition in Executor constructor

The same code was used in ROS bouncy but for some reason I am receiving the above mentioned error on Crystal.

The source of the issue is caused when assigning the executor `rclcpp::executors::SingleThreadedExecutor executor;`.

I am currently trying to pass arguments on assignment to avoid this error message.
Was there any changes to how the executors should be called on crystal?

---

Update:

I tried to reproduce the error message using a simple example using a pure ROS package.
I received a different error message this time but, I believe it something to do with the original issue I am facing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rclcpp/executor.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/string.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"


    std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> master_node;
    
    
        void static topic_callback(std_msgs::msg::String::SharedPtr msg)
      {
        std::cout  <<" Subscriber Received [" << msg->data << "]" << std::endl;
      }
    
    
    int main(){
    rclcpp::init(0, nullptr);
    
    rclcpp::executors::MultiThreadedExecutor executor;
    master_node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("MasterNode");
    auto subscription_ = master_node->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>("TopicName",topic_callback);
    
    executor.add_node(master_node);
    
    
    executor.spin_node_some(master_node);
    
    }
```

Just to give a little background on what I am trying to do.
Script A is the main code. I will initialize ROS and create a node in script B.

The `std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> master_node;` is being saved in a Header file of script B which will be used as a global variable.

Other scrips will use this pointer to create their publishers and subscribers.
For example script C will create a publisher `publisher_ = master_node->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>("topic");` and script D will subscribe to said publisher or other publishers `subscription_ = master_node->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>("TopicName",topic_callback);` .

The reason I want to use (Single/Multi)ThreadingExecutor is due to main code's thread being used in other matters.

---

Update2:

I believe the following is a better representation of my current code.

```
using rclcpp::executors::MultiThreadedExecutor;



std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> master_node;


    void topic_callback(std_msgs::msg::String::SharedPtr msg)
  {
    std::cout  <<" Subscriber Received [" << msg->data << "]" << std::endl;
  }


int main(){
rclcpp::init(0, nullptr);

MultiThreadedExecutor executor;
master_node = rclcpp::Node::make_shared("MasterNode");
auto subscription_ = master_node->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>("TopicName",topic_callback);

executor.add_node(master_node);
std::thread executor_thread(std::bind(&MultiThreadedExecutor::spin, &executor));
executor_thread.detach();
while(true){
std::cout << "hey" << std::endl;
usleep(3000000);
}
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314295/%5Bros2-crystal%5D--rclcpp::executors-interrupt-guard-condition/) by [Obeseturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39489/obeseturtle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 185 on 2019-01-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2019-01-31**:
To be clear, does the snippet above run and then crash?

**Comment by [Obeseturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39489/obeseturtle/) on 2019-01-31**:
The update1 code will crash.
The update2 code ran without issue.
Because I did not see the same error message when using the Update2's code, I began to suspect that some other issue was occurring. It seems that the **Interrupt guard condition** also occurs if `init` is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This can happen if the executor is created after `rclcpp::shutdown` is called or SIGINT is received, either due to ctrl-c or something else signaling.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2019-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Obeseturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39489/obeseturtle/) on 2019-01-30**:
I initialized ROS using `rclcpp::init(0, nullptr);` I have created a couple of publishers with no issue.  If my understanding is correct this would mean that the shutdown has not been called.

This issue only effects the subscribers. Is there something I am not setting correctly?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2019-01-30**:
Can you link a minimal example? Maybe I can spot something that way, but nothing off the top of my head.

**Comment by [Obeseturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39489/obeseturtle/) on 2019-01-30**:
Sure, Ill add the information as an edit to my original question.
Thank you for taking the time out of your day to answer my question.

**Comment by [Obeseturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39489/obeseturtle/) on 2019-01-31**:
Hi,

It seems that the script C constructor was being initialized before script B. The error message seen was due to the ROS node not being initialized. This is why the example I provided in my Update2: worked but it didn't on the main script.

**Comment by [petal](https://answers.ros.org/users/35592/petal/) on 2019-07-20**:
Hello! Did you solve this issue?

**Comment by [Obeseturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/39489/obeseturtle/) on 2019-07-22**:
Yes, it is just an issue of initializing the ROS node before creating a PUB/SUB.
If you Like you can create your own ticket so I can see the code and help you out.